# Synonymize [moustache] to [mustache], or burninate [moustache]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, synonym-request

> Note that once a tag has no uses it is removed from the system within 24 hours.

So this [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) is ultimately unnecessary but will be kept as a blacklist target in case the tag pops up again. (H/T: PetterFriberg) Original follows below.

---

[moustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moustache) is a misspelling of [mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mustache), referring to the [template library](https://mustache.github.io/).

I have corrected the 5 existing question instances, replacing [moustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moustache) with [mustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mustache).

I propose that either:

- someone [create a synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mustache/synonyms) (I don't have sufficient tag rep to suggest one); or
- we burninate [moustache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/moustache) as it seems like a fairly rare mistake

Being a neophyte to tag modifications, I'm not sure which is the more desirable course of action.

Comment: You'll have to pass out gas masks when this happens as burning moustache's stink ;)

Comment: [YouTube has a handy video walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSMFY7GoI1I) if anyone is still confused

Comment: You actually already solved the problem, the tag will be automatically removed in 24h, good work! This meta does not have much sense, you can wait for mod to re-tag it [status-completed] or just delete it and be happy with your work.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Oh, cool, I didn't know that would happen! I'll keep that in mind for future so as not to pollute meta. It seems Bhargav has already taken care of retagging it, so I'll leave it for posterity.

Comment: @PetterFriberg For posterity it's better to keep the question (i.e someone recreates it and we need to blacklist). I mod flagged for the completed tag

Comment: @msanfordm perfect again nice work, thanks. As some additional info normally the community  don't make synonym for misspelling but instead it do what you did

Comment: @PetterFriberg That was actually my sub-question: better to create a synonym? But looking at the existing synonyms it didn't look like they were _corrective_ synonyms, but _conceptual._ Glad I did the right thing, and thanks for the additional info!